# Excel VBA Loop Through Range and Delete Text Before Space As Well As Space

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro to delete text in cells before a space as well as the space itself.

I had thought this would work but it deletes the entire contents of each cell.

Can anyone see the issue?

```
Sub Trim()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        r.Value = Split(" ", r.Value)(0)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Split is expression then delimiter and you probably need (1) rather than (0).

Comment: Does your set contain one space always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check syntax before posting as your use of Split has the arguments the wrong way around.  If you put your cursor in the keyword 'Split' and press F1 this will bring up the MS help page on Split for VBA.  When you read this help you will find that Split can be limited to how many splits it does.  This is useful if your text contains multiple spaces.

```
Sub Trim()

    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        ' Split will work without the " " as this is the default separator, 
        ' but its good practise to specify it
        r.Value = Split( r.Value," ", Limit:=2)(1)
    Next r
End Sub
```